# How does pip know what compiler to use when building a native code extension?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, ibm-mq, pymqi

I have both Visual Studio 2017 Community and TDM-GCC both installed on my Windows 10 box.  Everything is 64-bit.  I've been trying to pip install pymqi, but so far I haven't had much luck.

Without going into too many irrelevant details, I'm trying to get it to use TDM-GCC instead of msvc to build the C components of this package.  However, it keeps using msvc even though I don't have it set up in the command line environment I'm pip installing from (i.e. I didn't run the vcvars64.bat file).  I do, however, have TDM-GCC in the PATH.

How does pip find the compiler?  Is there some command line option I can specify to force pip to use a specific compiler?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to [configure it](https://docs.python.org/2/install/#location-and-names-of-config-files):
Create `distutils.cfg` file in `PYTHONPATH\Lib\distutils`
with this configuration:

`[build]
compiler=mingw32`

You can see famous issue [#18](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/18) for more info